# One more time about the connection of Weyl tensor and gravitational waves

Tags: general-relativity, maxwell-equations, gravitational-waves

There is differential identity with Weyl tensor and energy-momentum tensor:
$$
D^{\lambda}C_{\lambda \alpha \sigma \beta} = 4 \pi G \left(D_{\sigma}T_{\alpha \beta} - D_{\beta}T_{\alpha \sigma} + \frac{1}{3}(g_{\alpha \sigma}D_{\beta}T - g_{\alpha \beta}D_{\sigma}T)\right). \qquad (1)
$$
One says (Carroll, "Spacetime and geometry") that it "...can be thought of as a propagation equation for gravitational waves, in close analogy with Waxwell's equations $\partial_{\mu}F^{\mu \nu} = J^{\nu}$...".
But I don't see where is the close analogy of $(1)$ and Maxwell's equation. Can you make it clearer?

Comment: The covariant derivative takes the place of the partial derivative, the Weyl tensor that of the electromagnetic field tensor, ad the expression on the right... is simply not as easy as $J^\nu$.

Comment: @Danu : this analogy is far-fetched in this case.

Comment: Sure, but that's besides the point.